# Firebase - getting image URL

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show the image, that I've saved in Firebase database.

When I try to read my image URL, it returns `null`.
Name can be read, because it shows name..

Why is it happening? And how to get image URL saved in Firebase database?

[image]

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MyPetListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "MyPetListActivity";


    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Button petadd;
    List<Pet> lsPet;

    ImageView backTo; // layout : activity_my_pet_list.xml


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_pet_list);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        petadd = findViewById(R.id.petadd);
        backTo = findViewById(R.id.backTo);  //activity_my_pet_list뒤로 가기 버튼

        lsPet = new ArrayList<>();


        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pets").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String key = childSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG,key+"키키키");
                    Pet pet = childSnapshot.getValue(Pet.class);

                    pet.getPetname();
                    pet.getPetimagerul();

                    Log.wtf(TAG, "did you get name?"+pet.getPetname());
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "did u get image url?"+pet.getPetimagerul());
                    lsPet.add(pet);
                }

                RecyclerView recyclerview_dogs = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_dogs);
                PetAdapter petAdapter = new PetAdapter(MyPetListActivity.this,lsPet);
                recyclerview_dogs.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MyPetListActivity.this,3));
                recyclerview_dogs.setAdapter(petAdapter);

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "onCancelled: 펫이미지 가져오는데 문제 발생! ");
            }
        });
```

**Log**:

```
2019-06-27 14:54:15.291 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did u get image url?null
2019-06-27 14:54:15.295 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for petimageurl found on class com.example.together.Model.Pet
2019-06-27 14:54:15.295 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did you get name?SmileDog
2019-06-27 14:54:15.298 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did u get image url?null
2019-06-27 14:54:15.301 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for petimageurl found on class com.example.together.Model.Pet
2019-06-27 14:54:15.301 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did you get name?NullDog
2019-06-27 14:54:15.317 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did u get image url?null
2019-06-27 14:54:15.319 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for petimageurl found on class com.example.together.Model.Pet
2019-06-27 14:54:15.319 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did you get name?Cute Dog ~
2019-06-27 14:54:15.327 5993-5993/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did u get image url?null
```

**Model:**

```
package com.example.together.Model;

public class Pet {

    private String petimageurl;
    private String petname;
    private String petbreed;
    private String petweight;
    private String birthday;
    private String gender;
    private String intro;
    private String petid;



    public Pet(){

    }

    public Pet(String petimageurl, String petname){
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
        this.petname = petname;

    }


    public Pet(String petimageurl, String petname, String intro){
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
        this.petname = petname;
        this.intro = intro;

    }


    public Pet(String petimageurl, String petname, String petbreed, String petweight, String birthday, String gender, String intro, String petid) {
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
        this.petname = petname;
        this.petbreed = petbreed;
        this.petweight = petweight;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.intro = intro;
        this.petid = petid;
    }


    public String getPetid() {
        return petid;
    }

    public void setPetid(String petid) {
        this.petid = petid;
    }

    public String getPetimagerul() {
        return petimageurl;
    }

    public void setPetimageurl(String petimage) {
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
    }

    public String getPetname() {
        return petname;
    }

    public void setPetname(String petname) {
        this.petname = petname;
    }

    public String getPetbreed() {
        return petbreed;
    }

    public void setPetbreed(String petbreed) {
        this.petbreed = petbreed;
    }

    public String getPetweight() {
        return petweight;
    }

    public void setPetweight(String petweight) {
        this.petweight = petweight;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getIntro() {
        return intro;
    }

    public void setIntro(String intro) {
        this.intro = intro;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You are setting as this - 

 public void setPetimageurl(String petimage) {
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
    }

Make it - 

 public void setPetimageurl(String petimageurl) {
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
    }
```

Change petimage to petimageurl

Comment: 2019-06-27 15:28:08.318 7077-7077/com.example.blogapp W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [-1x-1]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model

Even if i change it, it still show me null

Comment: First make the change and then try again

Comment: Yes i already make the change but still show to me null in my logcat

Comment: sorry ! i was see another persons message and try checking source TT

Comment: 2019-06-27 15:42:47.755 7363-7363/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did u get image url?null
2019-06-27 15:42:47.757 1870-1891/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2019-06-27 15:42:47.774 7363-7363/com.example.blogapp W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [-1x-1]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model

Comment: String image = childSnapshot.child("petimageurl").getValue() + "";

Try fetching the image like this and try once.

Comment: childSnapshot.child("petimageurl").getValue() + ""; 
This is show me not null amazizing but i don't understand

Comment: There is some problem with your model. Check it thoroughly. It will work fine.

Comment: Cheers. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in the `setPetimageurl`, change it to,

```
public void setPetimageurl(String petimage) {
    this.petimageurl = petimage; // you must use petimage instead petimageurl to set the value petimage to the local variable petimageurl
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: after i change it, it still show to me null in my logcat why this happend?

Comment: 2019-06-27 15:28:08.318 7077-7077/com.example.blogapp W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [-1x-1]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model

Even if i change it, it still show me null

Answer (score 1):

Change this-

```
 public void setPetimageurl(String petimage) {
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
    }
```

to-

```
public void setPetimageurl(String petimageurl) {
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
    }
```

Comment: but after i change it, it still show to me null in my logcat why this happend?

Comment: have you change this public void setPetimageurl(String petimage) {
        this.petimageurl = petimageurl;
    }??

Comment: 2019-06-27 15:42:47.755 7363-7363/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did u get image url?null
2019-06-27 15:42:47.757 1870-1891/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2019-06-27 15:42:47.774 7363-7363/com.example.blogapp W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [-1x-1]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model

Comment: does this Pet pet = childSnapshot.getValue(Pet.class); contain any value try printing this.

Comment: Log.wtf(TAG, "did you get petweight? : "+pet.getPetweight());
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "did you get Birthday?: "+pet.getBirthday());
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "did you get name?"+pet.getPetname());
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "did u get image url?"+pet.getPetimagerul());

i try to check my logcat it show everything in my log except url

Comment: String image = childSnapshot.child("petimageurl").getValue() + ""; 
childSnapshot.child("petimageurl").getValue() + ""
it shows the image uri OMG

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in the setter method

```
public void setPetimageurl(String petimage) {
    this.petimageurl = petimageurl; // typo
}
```

To avoid such situation use @PropertyName with public field and don't use getter setter or use @PropertyName with getter setter as well.

```
@PropertyName("petimageurl")
public String petimageurl;
```

Comment: But still show me null 
2019-06-27 15:42:47.755 7363-7363/com.example.blogapp E/MyPetListActivity: did u get image url?null
2019-06-27 15:42:47.757 1870-1891/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2019-06-27 15:42:47.774 7363-7363/com.example.blogapp W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [-1x-1]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model

Comment: @TTimfirst I suggest you to print the whole data you are getting by using getValue(String.class)